# How can I write an efficient loop to solve this Code Wars problem?

Tags: list, iteration, multiplication

The problem is the following:

This is a problem taken from code wars and titled 'Is my friend cheating?'
. A friend of mine takes a sequence of numbers from 1 to n (where n > 0).
. Within that sequence, he chooses two numbers, a and b.
. He says that the product of a and b should be equal to the sum of all numbers in the sequence, excluding a and b.
. Given a number n, could you tell the numbers he excluded from the sequence?

The function takes the parameter: n (n is always strictly greater than 0) and returns an array or a string of the form:

It happens that there are several possible (a, b). The function returns an empty array (or an empty string) if no possible numbers are found which will prove that my friend has not told the truth!

Example of returned sequence:
removNb(26) should return [(15, 21), (21, 15)]

I have tried a simple loop sequence:

```
def remov_nb(n):

somme  = 0
liste = []

for num in range (n+1):
    somme += num
    
for a in range(n+1):
    for b in range(n+1):
        if a * b == (somme-a-b):
            liste.append((a,b))

return (liste)
```

and also used itertools:

```
def remov_nb(n):
from itertools import product 
liste = []
somme = sum(x for x in range(1,n+1))

for x,y in product(range(1,n+1), range(1,n+1)):
    if (somme - x - y) == (x * y):
        liste.append((x,y))
return liste
```

The function doesn't work on Code Wars for lack of efficiency.

Can someone guide me here?

Comment: You must play around with the algebra. First, try to find a simple formula for the sum of all integers from 1 to n. Then write down the equation of the rule ("The product of a and b equals...") and rearrange it so that a and b are on one side, and n on the other. Then try to separate a and b. Then you will see a much faster solution.

Comment: Thank you, I was too stuck into coding to consider algebra optimization. I modified the function according to your suggestion and passed all the tests. This was very helpful, thanks again.